# Clock toggles only once from 0 to 1 and then stops toggling

Tags: verilog

```
initial begin 

clock =0 ;

end

always@(clock) begin 

$display("Inside clock always block");
#40 clock = ~ clock;
end
```

When I simulate this , clock changes from 0 to 1 and then stays 1. Why do I see just one toggle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
always
  #40 clock = ~ clock;
```

Presumably nothing else is driving `clock`, so because you had `clock` in the sensitivity list, `clock` never changed again and so the always block never executed again.

Comment: What about the trigger that happens from inside the always block ? At time t=0, the clock changes from X to 0 . So, the always block starts executing . An event gets scheduled at time t= 40 , which toggles the clock from 0 to 1. However this toggle from 0 to 1, should initiate the execution of the always block again . Am I missing something here ?

Comment: I think so. Yes `clock` changes at time 40, but the always block is still executing then so it misses the trigger.

Comment: I see your point . Thanks . I thought I was using the non blocking assignment . Hence the confusion . It is perfectly clear now . Thanks again